# Hi, in my php application I would like to use stream_copy_to_stream

Tags: php

in my php application I would like to use "stream_copy_to" for download a file from internet, but because the file could be quite long I would like to keep trace of progress in a javascript progress-bar. How can I do that ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the event data in a database table and while the copy runs you can fire an AJAX request to a php script to return progress:

1. Compare the total file size to the current file size (method
   described below).
2. Not use `stream_copy_to_stream` and instead use a loop to copy small chunks at a time, periodically updating a bytes_received column in the database

**General approach**

Before you start the `stream_copy_to_stream` you get the `Content-Length` header (if available) and store it in a database table or other for future comparison.

While the `stream_copy_to_stream` executes, use an AJAX request to a php script that compares the output file size to the content length and returns a percentage that is used in the progress bar.

```
$sourceFile = 'your-source-file';
$destFile = 'your-destination-file-name';
$source = fopen($sourceFile, 'r'); 
$headers = parseHeaders(stream_get_meta_data($source)['wrapper_data']);
if ($headers['response_code'] == 200 && isset($headers['Content-Length']))
{
    // insert $destFile, $headers['Content-Length'] into database
    // return the ID to frontend for progress checks
}
$dest = fopen($destFile, 'w');
stream_copy_to_stream($source, $dest);
```

You could use a function such as this to parse the headers

```
function parseHeaders($headers)
{
    $head = array();
    foreach( $headers as $k=>$v )
    {
        $t = explode(':', $v, 2);
        if (isset($t[1] ))
            $head[trim($t[0])] = trim($t[1]);
        else
        {
            $head[] = $v;
            if(preg_match("#HTTP/[0-9\.]+\s+([0-9]+)#",$v,$out))
                $head['reponse_code'] = intval($out[1]);
        }
    }
    return $head;
}
```

Front-end you would fire the AJAX request to start the copy, that would return the ID and Content-Length information to setup the progress bar.

While the copy is running would fire an AJAX request on an interval to check on the progress and update the progress bar.

```
// get the file information from the database based on the ID
    // $totalSize = Content-Length data from database
$currentSize = filesize($destFile);
$progress = min(100, 100 * $currentSize / $totalSize);
echo json_encode(array('progress' => $progress));
```